# Azure Service Bus ReceiveBatch returning 0 messages

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have well over 1000 messages in my topic subscription.

When I call Receive I get a message as expected.
When I call ReceiveBatch I get 0 messages back.

What could the problem be?

```
MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(Config.ServiceBusTopicConnectionString);
var path = SubscriptionClient.FormatSubscriptionPath(topicPath, subscriptionName);
var receiver = factory.CreateMessageReceiver(path, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

var messages = receiver.ReceiveBatch(50); //This returns 0 messages
//var message = receiver.Receive(); //This returns 1 message as expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled batching on the topic?

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh528527.aspx

Batching occurs across all entities that enable batched store access.
When creating a new queue, topic or subscription, batched store access is enabled by default. To disable batched store access, set the EnableBatchedOperations property to false before creating the entity. For example:

C#

```
QueueDescription qd = new QueueDescription();
qd.EnableBatchedOperations = false;
Queue q = namespaceManager.CreateQueue(qd);
```

Batched store access does not affect the number of billable messaging operations, and is a property of a queue, topic, or subscription. It is independent of the receive mode and the protocol that is used between a client and the Service Bus service.

Comment: I did not create the topic, how would I check for this?

Comment: check the EnableBatchedOperations  property of the TopicDescription